# calling variables from typescript file in html template [angular]

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I just started working with angular after reading the docs. I'm still a newbie.

Calling arrays in angular2  is simple:

you just have to use *ngfor item of items and then  {{item.name}}.

what if I'm calling a single object, string or any, from my ts file . How can I do that?

I tried :

```
{{myvariable}}
```

or

```
<div  ng-init="let x = myvariable">   {{x.name}}</div>
```

and other stuff but it doesn't work.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no `ng-init` in Angular2. I don't get what you try to accomplish. What did you expect to happen with `{{myvariable}} `?

Comment: my var is an object . I wanna show its name and id in html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{{myvariable.id}} {{myvariable.name}}
```

or if the variable is not initialized yet when the component is created.

```
{{myvariable?.id}} {{myvariable?.name}}
```

Comment: thanks, it works. how can html show {{myvariable?.id}} if it's not  initialized?

Comment: "if it's not initialized yet ...". This means `?.` avoids getting an error when `myvariable` is `undefined` or `null` but when it gets an value assigned eventually it will show the value.

Comment: I can't see how `co.myvar` might be related to `<p>{{myvar.name}}</p>`. Please update your question and add more code.

Answer (score 2):

the variable you are trying to access in your template should be available as public property on your component. e.g. in your component if you have myvar as public property with statement like public myvar : any; and then some where in life cycle hooks or other method of component if you assign that to an object e.g. in ngOnInit if you do 
    this.myvar = {
      p1 : 2
    }
 then you can access properties of myvar in your template like {{myvar.p1}}